# Ignore a function with Protobuf.NET

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.None)]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(A))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(B))]

public interface INode
{
    IQueryable BuildQueryable();
}
```

It is inherited by classes A and B. When I try to serialize a concrete instance of the interfaces type i.e.:

```
INode ANode = new A();
```

I am getting the following error from Protobuf.net saying that IQueryable is not serializable:

```
InvalidOperationException: No serializer defined for type: System.Linq.IQueryable
```

How can I ignore this function (that returns an IQueryable) from from trying to get serialized?

Comment: Haven't used protobuf in a while but certainly don't remember it serializing functions, that makes no sense. Are you sure there isn't an explicitly marked field which uses this type?

Comment: Oh okay you were right. One of the subclasses was trying to serialize the field, removing that cleared it up. Cheers! @Rotem